# question on exercise about random walk

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

Let $Y_1, Y_2, ....$ be iid random variables with $Y_i = \pm 1$ with equal probability.
Define random variables $X_0 = 0$ and $X_k = Y_1+ ...+ Y_k$.
I'm trying to understand the solution to the exercise: Given two positive integers $A$ and $B$ what is the probability that random walk reaches $A$ before $-B$?

Solution: Let $\tau$ be the first time at which the rw reaches $A$ or $-B$. Define
$$
f(k)= P(X_\tau = A | X_0 = k). 
$$
The answer we are looking for is then $f(0)$.
It is easy to solve from the recursive formula
$$
f(k) = \frac12 f(k+1) + \frac12 f(k-1). 
$$

question: I don't understand how this recursive formula is found (no explanation in the solution). I get as far as:
$$ 
f(k)= P(X_\tau = A | X_0 = k) = P(X_\tau = A | X_1 = k+1) P(X_1 = k+1|X_0 = k) +   P(X_\tau = A | X_1 = k-1) P(X_1 = k-1| X_0 = k).
$$
Then $P(X_1 = k+1|X_0 = k) = P(X_1 = k+1|X_0 = k) = 1/2$ so
$$
f(k)= \frac12 P(X_\tau = A | X_1 = k+1)  + \frac12  P(X_\tau = A | X_1 = k-1).
$$
But $P(X_\tau = A | X_1 = k+1)$ is not $f(k+1)$ so I don't the formula...

How can I get the formula?
Any clarifications are appreciated. thank you!

Comment: If you are at $k$ then there are two paths to reaching $A$. Either you draw a $+1$ and then need to reach $A$ from $k+1$ or you draw a $-1$ and then need to reach $A$ from $k-1$.  That's the recursion.

Comment: I get that's how the recursion works. what I don't get is the solution... $f(k)$ starts at $t=0$ and end at $t = \tau$. but when I use this $f$ from the solution to get the recursion, I get something starting at $t=1$ and end at $t = \tau$. I'm having difficulty seeing how they are still the same function $f$ but evaluated at different values.

Comment: $\tau$ isn't important here.  $f(k)$ is the probability that you end in state $A$ given that you start in state $k$, treating $A,B$ as terminal states (I mean, the game stops as soon as you reach one or the other).